# Is there a way to direct light toward the same location regardless of the angle of incidence?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

E.g., picture a circular hole in the center of a roof of an otherwise opaque cubical room on a sunny day. As the sun moves across the sky the spot will move across the floor and walls of the room, appearing in the center of the floor only when the sun is directly overhead. With a mirror, one might direct the light to appear in the center of the floor from any single incident angle but not from every incident angle. Is there a way, perhaps with a series of prisms or maybe some kind of waveguide or something, to direct the light to appear in the center of the floor regardless of where the sun is in the sky? I.e., for light to exit the apparatus always in the same direction regardless of the angle from which it entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do this perfectly with a static optical system. Think about the backwards-going rays: If they all originate from the same spot and are generally indistinguishable, they will always emit in the same distribution of directions. There is nothing time-dependent about the optical system, so a static input will result in a static output. The ideal solution for your general problem would use mirrors which track the location of the sun to focus the maximum power on the target at all times.

That said, if you constrain the possible location of the sun (which we can do from prior knowledge), and you consider it a success to hit a large target, then using a suitable parabolic mirror or some such would work much of the time. Alternatively, if you consider it a success that *some* light always hits the target, then you can make the room a big [integrating sphere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_sphere), resulting in a uniform illumination of the interior.

Comment: What if a number of off-axis paraboloidal mirrors were arrayed around the hole with a secondary reflector of some type directly over the hole and the paraboloidal mirrors' focal points all at the secondary reflector which would then reflect the light down the hole? Could that work? I assume the spot's brightness would fluctuate as the sun moved between mirrors but this could be minimized by using larger numbers of smaller mirrors, yes?

Comment: What if the secondary reflector was a convex paraboloidal mirror and the focal points of the concave primary mirrors were, like, inside the convex mirror, on the spot on the ground?

Comment: Could a lens across the hole be better than a second mirror above the hole?

Answer (score 0):

No, because this is forbidden by time reversal symmetry.
In other words, imagine the light travelling in the opposite direction - you cannot know where it is supposed to go without building in some sort of mechanical "time of day" mechanism.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced that it's impossible. The rays converging at the spot on the floor can come from different angles. Consider the [focus-to-focus reflection property of the ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Focus-to-focus_reflection_property). Inside a reflective ellipse, all rays passing through one focus also pass through the other focus.

Comment: @PM2Ring - all rays going from point A to point B does not violate time reversal symmetry  ....   the OP here needs "all rays from many points going to one point"

Comment: The incoming rays are coming from a range of altitude & azimuth angles, but they're passing through a fairly small circle in the roof. Another option (more practical than turning the room into a reflective ellipsoid) is to use a fibre optic lamp in reverse, or a [light tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_tube).

Comment: @PM2Ring  the OP is a little unclear but does seem to want the light to exit in the same direction, which a light tube won't do ... but if the OP's only desire is to illuminate a spot on the floor and doesn't mind a pipe going from the ceiling straight down to that spot, then a light tube would work ...  but if all the OP wants is the light to enter the room then a light tube doesn't add anything

Comment: @PM2Ring "a fibre optic lamp in reverse" occurred to me as well. The tubes could be arrayed such that they all directed light to the same spot on the floor, though only a subset of them could be facing the sun at any given time.